# EOFError when reading a line. Can you please explain?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this input statement in my program:

```py
input("Enter another number: ')
```

When trying to run the program, I get EOFError when reading a line. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you start and end the string with different types of quotes

Comment: Presumably your code is being run within someone else's environment, and they have the input pre-loaded. Getting an EOFError means there is simply no input left to read. It's likely that you aren't implementing the requirements correctly, and are either trying to read too many lines of input, or accidentally read an extra line of input earlier when you shouldn't have

Comment: You prob. need to put this `error` message into some more `context` so it's easier to help you.  @GreenCloakGuy got some good points...

Comment: That code will generate *SyntaxError: unterminated string literal...* and **not** EOFError

Answer (score 0):

When you add a *string* value to your code, make sure it starts and ends with `''` , `""` or `"""`, otherwise it will throw an error:

```
input("Enter another number: ") 
input('Enter another number: ') 
input("""Enter another number: """)
```

With respect to the `EOF` *end of file* error, you can take a look at the following [resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/correcting-eof-error-in-python-in-codechef/) to understand why it happens with `input()` and `raw_input()` functions.

Comment: while this is an error in OP's code, it's not actually answering the question. That would be a SyntaxError, not the EOFError which OP is asking about

Comment: @green-cloak-guy `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` That what it throws.

Comment: That's not an EOF ("end-of-file") error. You can reproduce OP's example by running an `input()` call in a python REPL and pressing ctrl+D to close the input stream.

Comment: @green-cloak-guy thanks, it would be great if the OP included a bit more information about it's input and work space